# Using Firebase from google instead of react-native-firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

At the moment I am using react-native-firebase 4.3.8, but I noticed that google has updated firebase (firestore in particular), which holds some interesting new features. I was trying to use firebase from google directly, but it gives me errors (can't find variable: document) for example.

Is it possible to use firebase instead of react-native-firebase, so the updated features are available.

I know that react-native-firebase are working on an update (v5) to include those features.

Answer (score 1):

To use Firebase within your React Native application you need to bind the JavaScript code to the underlying native iOS/Android SDK. When you use [Invertase's `react-native-firebase` library](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) they take care of that for you.

You can definitely use another library that does the same, or roll your own. But recommending a library is off-topic on Stack Overflow, and showing you how to do this yourself is a bit too broad for a question here.

If you're having problems getting the Invertase library to work, it is best if you share the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That way we can see what you tried, and help you get unstuck.

If none of these apply, you will have to wait until the feature you want it available in the library. Note that Invertase's react-native-firebase library is open source, so they might be taking pull requests in case you want to help.

Comment: Thank Frank, I think I will wait for react-native-firebase to update their product.